# useCallback with updated state object - React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, usecallback

I have a `POST` API call that I make on a button click. We have one large state object that gets sent as `body` for a `POST` call. This state object keeps getting updated based on different user interactions on the page.

```
function QuotePreview(props) {
  const [quoteDetails, setQuoteDetails] = useState({});
  const [loadingCreateQuote, setLoadingCreateQuote] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if(apiResponse?.content?.quotePreview?.quoteDetails) {
      setQuoteDetails(apiResponse?.content?.quotePreview?.quoteDetails);
    }
  }, [apiResponse]);

  const onGridUpdate = (data) => {
    let subTotal = data.reduce((subTotal, {extendedPrice}) => subTotal + extendedPrice, 0);
    subTotal = Math.round((subTotal + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100

    setQuoteDetails((previousQuoteDetails) => ({
      ...previousQuoteDetails,
      subTotal: subTotal,
      Currency: currencySymbol,
      items: data,
    }));
  };

  const createQuote = async () => {
    try {
      setLoadingCreateQuote(true);
      const result = await usPost(componentProp.quickQuoteEndpoint, quoteDetails);
      if (result.data?.content) {
        /** TODO: next steps with quoteId & confirmationId */
        console.log(result.data.content);
      }
      return result.data;
    } catch( error ) {
      return error;
    } finally {
      setLoadingCreateQuote(false);
    }
  };

  const handleQuickQuote = useCallback(createQuote, [quoteDetails, loadingCreateQuote]);

  const handleQuickQuoteWithoutDeals = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // remove deal if present
    if (quoteDetails.hasOwnProperty("deal")) {
      delete quoteDetails.deal;
    }
    handleQuickQuote();
  }

  const generalInfoChange = (generalInformation) =>{
    setQuoteDetails((previousQuoteDetails) => (
      {
        ...previousQuoteDetails,
        tier: generalInformation.tier,
      }
    ));
  }

  const endUserInfoChange = (endUserlInformation) =>{
    setQuoteDetails((previousQuoteDetails) => (
      {
        ...previousQuoteDetails,
        endUser: endUserlInformation,
      }
    ));
  }

  return (
    <div className="cmp-quote-preview">
      {/* child components [handleQuickQuote will be passed down] */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

when the `handleQuickQuoteWithoutDeals` function gets called, I am deleting a key from the object. But I would like to immediately call the API with the updated object. I am deleting the deal key directly here, but if I do it in an immutable way, the following API call is not considering the updated object but the previous one.

The only way I found around this was to introduce a new state and update it on click and then make use of the `useEffect` hook to track this state to make the API call when it changes. With this approach, it works in a weird way where it keeps calling the API on initial load as well and other weird behavior.

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear how any children would call the `handleQuickQuote` callback, but if you are needing to close over in callback scope a "copy" of the `quoteDetails` details then I suggest the following small refactor to allow this parent component to use the raw `createQuote` function while children receive a memoized callback with the current `quoteDetails` enclosed.

Consume `quoteDetails` as an argument:

```
const createQuote = async (quoteDetails) => {
  try {
    setLoadingCreateQuote(true);
    const result = await usPost(componentProp.quickQuoteEndpoint, quoteDetails);
    if (result.data?.content) {
      /** TODO: next steps with quoteId & confirmationId */
      console.log(result.data.content);
    }
    return result.data;
  } catch( error ) {
    return error;
  } finally {
    setLoadingCreateQuote(false);
  }
};
```

Memoize an "anonymous" callback that passes in the `quoteDetails` value:

```
const handleQuickQuote = useCallback(
  () => createQuote(quoteDetails),
  [quoteDetails]
);
```

Create a shallow copy of `quoteDetails`, delete the property, and call `createQuote`:

```
const handleQuickQuoteWithoutDeals = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const quoteDetailsCopy = { ...quoteDetails };

  // remove deal if present
  if (quoteDetailsCopy.hasOwnProperty("deal")) {
    delete quoteDetailsCopy.deal;
  }
  createQuote(quoteDetailsCopy);
}
```

Comment: I really love this answer. I think I complicated what might have been simple to do had I thought about it in a normal JS way? I am confused by this comment though "it's not clear how any children would call the handleQuickQuote callback". I am passing them down as props and triggering them on onClick. Hope that is not wrong. PS: I'll try your answer shortly and mark it as accepted. Ty.

Comment: @ThomasSebastian Oh, I meant that more as "I don't know if the children need to pass any args.... but based on current usage I assume they are simply invoking with the quote closed over within the callback". I think my assumption was correct though.